# How to properly use :default-directory in Flycheck checker definition?

Tags: use-package, flycheck

I'm trying to use a somewhat [new property that has been introduced to Flycheck checker definition syntax recently](https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/pull/973), and I don't think I'm doing it properly. I believe the `:default-directory` property should be passed a callable that returns the directory to be set, but I don't think it works the way I think it does.

Here's my attempt to create a new checker that works the same way as `php-phpcs`, but with the property specified:

```
(use-package! flycheck
  :config
  (flycheck-define-checker php-phpcs-jetpack
    "A PHP style checker using PHP Code Sniffer for Jetpack."
    :command ("phpcs" "--report=checkstyle"
              "-q"
              (option "--standard=" flycheck-phpcs-standard concat)
              (eval
               (-when-let* ((fname buffer-file-name)
                            (ext (file-name-extension fname)))
                 (concat "--extensions=" ext)))

              (eval (when (buffer-file-name)
                      (concat "--stdin-path=" (buffer-file-name))))
              "-")
    :standard-input t
    :error-parser flycheck-parse-checkstyle
    :default-directory (lambda () "/home/zinigor/workspace/jetpack/")
    :error-filter
    (lambda (errors)
      (flycheck-sanitize-errors
       (flycheck-remove-error-file-names "STDIN" errors)))
    :modes (php-mode php+-mode)
    :predicate flycheck-buffer-nonempty-p))
```

Am I using the `lambda` definition correctly? My main idea is to first try forcing the checker to always use a predefined directory, and then I'll expand the idea when it works for me.